# Search Java array using a non-static method

Tags: java, arrays

I have array of Object type Employee:

```
Employee[] employees = new Employee[100];
```

Each Employee is

```
Employee(FirstName, LastName, MiddleInitial, Status, Gender, EN);
```

Each employee when they are created are add to the array. I'm using a non-static method where you enter the employee number, and it returns the array index.

I have `public int getIndex(EN)`. How can I search the array to return the index where `EN` is located, I'm trying to using .equals currently, like `e1.equals(e2)` to detect the `EN`, but I don't think I have overridden it properly to work....

Thanks!

Comment: Please don't use Arrays. There are collections to reduce your code.

Comment: what do you mean "EN is located"? plus if you are using equals show us your equals override. and what's EN?

Comment: What I mean is where say EN = 10000, it will search for the array index where EN is also 10000

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to search using the `EN` instead of using the `equals()` method. You could use the `equals()` method too, if you've overridden it in your `Employee` class accordingly(is the EN is equal, then the Employee objects are equal).

Normally, you could do something like this:-

```
public int getIndex(EN){
    int myIndex = -1;
    for(int i=0;i<empArray.length;i++){
        if(empArray[i].getEN()==EN){// Assuming EN is a number, else if its a String, use the equals() method.
            myIndex = i;
            break;
        }
    }
    return myIndex;
}
```

You could even use the `for-each` loop instead of the standard `for` loop, but you'll have to maintain the counter yourself in that case.

Answer (score 0):

```
public int getIndex(EN){
   iterate over your array
      if item.EN equals EN 
         return index
      end of if
   end of loop
   return -1 // default for not found case
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
but I don't think I have overridden it properly to work....
```

How will your .equals() method work the? Default equals() method in Object class `simply performs a == operation` and returns the boolean value. Since you are storing distinct employee  objects in the array you will always get false value.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to compare to a static value then simply do:

```
for(Employee curr : employees)
{
   if(curr.getEN() == 10000)
     // do your magic
}
```